# Can I copy a closure in Scala?

Tags: scala, closures

This is perhaps a half-baked idea, but can I copy the environment of an expression?  Consider the following example:

```
class foo[T](block: => T) {
  var data = { () => block }
  def run() = { data() }
}

var a = 5

var b = new foo({ a += 1; println(a) })
var c = new foo({ a += 1; println(a) })

b.run()
c.run()
b.run()
c.run()
```

I get the following output:

```
6
7
8
9
```

But what I *really* want is the following:

```
6
6
7
7
```

In short, I want `foo` to have copies of the variables in the block instead of referring to them, once the initial value has been resolved. Can this be done?  [scala.util.DynamicVariable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/DynamicVariable.html) seems promising, but I'm having a hard time understanding how I might use it in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're closing over a (and thus changing its value as your program runs), rather than closing over a different variable initialized from a.  You might want to try something more like this:

```
class bar[T](block: (T) => T, a: T) {
  var cur = a
  def run() = { cur = block(cur); cur }
}

var a = 5

var b = new bar((r: Int) => { val q = r + 1; println(q); q }, a)
var c = new bar((r: Int) => { val q = r + 1; println(q); q }, a)

b.run()
c.run()
b.run()
c.run()
```

Output:

```
6
6
7
7
```

However, note that unlike your code, this will not affect the value of the `a` variable as it runs.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make a copy, then why not make a copy?

```
 var c = new foo({ var aa = a + 1; println(aa) })
```

If you want to take an existing closure that refers to a variable, and turn it into a closure that refers to a copy of that variable, then I'm afraid it's not possible.

In any case, mutable variables should not be used except in very rare circumstances and in a very controlled manner. That is, not juggling their references.

Answer (score 0):

1) As n.m. already mentioned, you should prefer immutable concepts when using closures.

2) On the other hand this is exactly what closures are for. They don't capture the **value** of the variabe, they capture the **variable** itself! Your question is kinda upside-down. You actually are capturing the environment - the environment of your variable. If you don't need the same variable than copy it as n.m. or Ian McLaird respectively suggested.